# calculate the rendering of a custom control

Tags: xpages

In an xpage I would like to be able to decide which custom controls have to be rendered or loaded.
I have a custom control named 1, another 2, 3 etc
When a scoped variable has the value 1, custom control 1 should be displayed/rendered/loaded.
A value of 2 , custom control 2 has to be displayed. etc

I came up with following sollution :
I calculate if that custom control has to be loaded or not depending on the value of the scoped variable.

Since I have 8 of these custom controls on 1 page I was wondering ,since only 1 out of those 8 custom controls have to be rendered ,if there isn't a better way with less code to do the same job. Won't my sollution put a lot of load to my server ?

Comment: Did you look at the Extension library? It has a dynamic load control

Comment: Sven and David have both good solution for your problem but keep in mind it also depends on the Content of your controls. With David Leedy's solution i ran in some Troubles in combindation with xe:dialog,xe:form and partial refresh, sometimes it may be better to simply place all controls and calculate the loaded Attribute (use a bean for that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sven's solution looks absolutely brilliant but also kinda scary at the same time.  Though I'm definitely going to play with that.

There is a more "out of the box" possibility that might work for you.  the Dynamic Content Control of the extension library.  My understanding is that it's designed for exactly this.  You still need to predefine your custom controls (unlike Sven's Java injection) but the dynamic content control is better performing then trying to control all the rendering manually.  There's a demo in the ext. library demo app but heres a snippet I've used:

```
<xe:dynamicContent
                id="dynamic">
                <xp:this.facets>

                    <xp:panel
                        xp:key="cat">
                        <xc:cc_form_category></xc:cc_form_category>
                    </xp:panel>
                    <xp:panel
                        xp:key="subCategory">
                        <xc:cc_form_subCategory></xc:cc_form_subCategory>
                    </xp:panel>
                    <xp:panel
                        xp:key="rental">
                        <xc:cc_form_rentalID></xc:cc_form_rentalID>
                    </xp:panel>
                    <xp:panel
                        xp:key="default">default content</xp:panel>

                </xp:this.facets>
            </xe:dynamicContent>
```

That's basically the setup of the custom controls.  then I've been using some Client Side JavaScript when I want to show one or make a change.

```
XSP.showContent("#{id:dynamic}","cat")
XSP.partialRefreshPost('#{id:mainPanel}', {})
```

I think if it kinda like a Switch Statement really.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Tried this, and I must say , it makes the code easier to maintain.
I have put the selection of the custom control in the afterpageload event.
I don't know if it's the best sollution performance wise.

Answer (score 3):

A better solution is to inject your custom control on the fly. This can be easily done with java:

```
package ch.hasselba.xpages;

import java.util.UUID;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.builder.ControlBuilder;
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.builder.ControlBuilder.ControlImpl;
import com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite;
import com.ibm.xsp.context.FacesContextExImpl;
import com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil;

public class XPagesUtil {

    public void injectCC( final String ccName , final String componentName ){
        FacesContextExImpl fc = (FacesContextExImpl) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        UIComponent cmp = FacesUtil.findChildComponent(fc.getViewRoot(), componentName );
        UIIncludeComposite objCtrl = new UIIncludeComposite();
        objCtrl.setPageName( ccName );
        objCtrl.setId("new_" + UUID.randomUUID() );
        ControlBuilder cBuilder = new ControlBuilder();
        ControlImpl<UIIncludeComposite> objImplControl = new ControlImpl<UIIncludeComposite>(objCtrl);
        ControlImpl<UIComponent> objImplParent =  new ControlImpl<UIComponent>(cmp);
        objImplParent.addChild(objImplControl);
        cBuilder.buildControl(fc,objImplParent,false);
    }
}
```

To use the code on your XPage, you now can do the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.afterPageLoad>
        <![CDATA[#{javascript:
            importPackage( ch.hasselba.xpages.extlib );
            var nameOfCC = "/IncludeCC.xsp";
            new ch.hasselba.xpages.XPagesUtil().injectCC(nameOfCC, "parent");
        }]]>
    </xp:this.afterPageLoad>

    <xp:div id="parent" />
</xp:view>
```

You can now calculate the variable *nameOfCC*.

Comment: Sven, this is a super solution! ) Thanks for sharing! I used this solution inside DataTable which is also built dynamically. Works perfect!
One tip for other who will use this solution: be sure that parent component (in Sven's example: "cmp") is already bound inside ViewRoot (added as children to the ViewRoot.getChildren List), otherwise you will get NullPointerException. (You may faced with such issue in case you build parent also dynamically).

Comment: @AndrewGrabovetskyi: You can also checkout a special component for injection of Custom Controls: https://github.com/hasselbach/domino-ccinjector